# how to make insert into without duplicate in mysql via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

i have a variable declare on my php like this

```
      $kode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["kode"]);
              $nama = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["nama"]);
              $hargabeli = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["hargabeli"]);
              $hargajual = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["hargajual"]);
              $keterangan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["keterangan"]);
              $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["brand"]);
              $kategori = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["kategori"]);
              $is_active = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["is_active"]);
              $image_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fileDestination);
              $sumber_pengadaan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["sumber_pengadaan_id"]);
              $supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["supplier_id"]);
              $remark = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["remark"]);
              $umur_penyusutan_barang = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["umur_penyusutan_barang"]);
              $umur_ekonomis = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["umur_ekonomis"]);
              $sumber_perolehan = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["sumber_perolehan"]);
              $tanggal_invoice = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['tanggal_invoice']));
```

for all those result, i made this sql on my php

```
sql2 = "insert into $tabeldatabase values( '$kode','$nama','$hargabeli','$hargajual','$keterangan','$kategori','','','','','','$brand','','', '$image_name', '', '$sumber_pengadaan','', '$supplier','', '$remark', '$umur_penyusutan_barang', '$umur_ekonomis', '', '$is_active', '$tanggal_invoice', '')";
```

but the problem is, if `$kode` was exists, the program automatically delete old data and replace with the new data, how to set the code based on this case, so if `kode` was exists, then it cant be inserted.

i think sort of this, but dont know if it's right or not

```
sql2 = "insert into $tabeldatabase values( '$kode','$nama','$hargabeli','$hargajual','$keterangan','$kategori','','','','','','$brand','','', '$image_name', '', '$sumber_pengadaan','', '$supplier','', '$remark', '$umur_penyusutan_barang', '$umur_ekonomis', '', '$is_active', '$tanggal_invoice', '') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $tabeldatabase WHERE kode = $kode)";
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Put a unique index on the column where `$kode` is supposed to go en use `INSERT IGNORE`\

Answer (score 0):

Just add `IGNORE` to your query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` ...
```

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/